# Installing cibonfire on windows using AMPP (not package)

Tags: php, codeigniter, bonfire

I'm trying to install CIBonfire for windows but the install always returns this :

[image]

Here's my `<VirtualHost>` configuration :

[image]

I'm quite new to learning Apache directives. Any help appreciated.

Thanks ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution:

1.enable `mod_rewrite` in your server, just try put this line at the top of your `.htaccess` page,

```
     RewriteEngine On
```

Or,

2.Open `bonfire/install/config/config.php` and `bonfire/bonfire/application/config/config.php` then fill up the value:

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php";
```

Good luck !

Comment: it works. I have another question though, why didn't it work before changing the value `$config['index_page']`?

Comment: because codeigniter/bonfire confuse what page to use, it seems your `mod_rewrite` is not configured properly, so you need to not to use that by determine the index page. look: http://cibonfire.com/docs/guides/installation.html also: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html